# Is it correct to say "to sacrifice A for B" or "to sacrifice A over B"?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

Let say you want to give up A so that you can take B. So,if that, then what should I say?

```
 to sacrifice A for B
```

or

```
to sacrifice A over B
```

Ex: Do you think ignorant people sacrifice the important thing over the trivial thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **sacrifice for** is more idiomatic.
>
> sacrifice someone or something ***for*** someone or something. ([TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sacrifice+for))

- It had also fostered a sense of unity among the Greek people, which
  would make them more willing to make sacrifices ***for*** the common good.
  (New York Times Jul 13, 2015)
- sacrifice A ***for*** B.

Answer (score 3):

Sacrifice A for B is correct for the meaning you are trying to achieve. To sacrifice A over B implies that you must pick either A or B to sacrifice for whatever it is you are trying to obtain.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're giving up A so we can have B, we *prefer* B *over* A.  The preposition *over* generally denotes the superior choice (both words imply elevation, after all).  So *sacrifice A over B* seems weird at least, if not downright backward.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sacrifice%20for%2C%20sacrifice%20over&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csacrifice%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csacrifice%20over%3B%2Cc0) *sacrifice for* is a much common expression than *sacrifice over*.

- *Sacrifice over* has a more formal connotation an is used mainly as a noun as in:

> - Some historians have argued that the characteristics on display in Scott's last expedition – the straitjacket of tradition, class prejudice, ***the glorification of sacrifice over achievement*** – indicated a nation well past its sell-by date.
> - Genesis tells us that God favored ***Abel's sacrifice over his brother Cain's.***  This was because Abel brought the very finest from his flocks, while Cain brought an average offering from his crops. In ancient times, it was common among the ...

- As for your sentence I suggest you use *sacrifice for*.

Comment: In neither example is *sacrifice* a verb, which is what OP seems to be asking about (since the verb determines the preposition).